# setInterval cuenta atrás de 2 en 2

Tags: javascript, html

Me gustaría hacer una cuenta atrás simple y funciona pero parece que ejecuta 2 veces el código por cada vez que arranca el `setInterval`.

```
<p id="timeout"></p>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var counter=10;
setInterval(function(){ counter=counter-1;document.getElementById('timeout').innerHTML=counter; }, 1000);

</script>
```

Comment: El contador va de uno en uno y funciona sin problemas. ¿Estás seguro de que no llamas al `setInterval` dos veces?

Comment: gracias a todos, me han servido todas las soluciones pero me ha llamado en especial la atención de dev joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se ejecutará sin parar ya que no tiene alguna condición dentro de la función.
Para validar esto y detenerlo. Por ejemplo cuando llegue a 0 el contador podríamos  obtener el `ID` que retorna la función, como dice la documentación [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

Teniendo este id podemos llamar a  [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) para parar la ejecución

```js
var counter=10;
var id = setInterval(function(){ 
   if(counter==0)
      clearInterval(id);
   else
   {
      counter=counter-1; 
      document.getElementById('timeout').innerHTML=counter; 
   }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="timeout"></p>
```

Si desea personalizar podría envolverlo en una función y pasar los parametros que requiera como valor inicial de `counter` etc.

```js
function interval(id,i){
    var counter=id;
    var id = setInterval(function(){ 
    if(counter==0)
    {
        clearInterval(id);
        interval(20,4);
    }
    else
    {
        counter=counter-i; 
        document.getElementById('timeout').innerHTML=counter; 
    }
    }, 1000);
}

interval(10,1);
```

```html
<p id="timeout"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

es porque el setInterval,, Funciona como un stop de codigo,, pasa un tiempo y se ejecuta el resto de codigo siguiente,, la mejor opcione es  hacer un ciclo , con el For,  Do-while, o while  para realizar iteraciones

Mejor toma este codigo como ejemplo del funcionamiento de  setInterval

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click "Try it". Wait 3 seconds, and the page will alert "Hello".</p>

<button onclick="setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert('Hello');
setTimeout(myFunction2, 3000);
}

function myFunction2() {
    alert('Hello2'); 
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Ejemplo del de un ciclo  de iteracion

```
<body>

<h1>JavaScript while</h1>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var text = "";
var i = 10;
while (i> 0) {
    text += "<br>The number is " + i;
    i=i-2;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>

</body>
```